How to Correctly Place a Stop-Limit Order Using MEXC API
I'm trying to place a stop-limit order on MEXC using their API, but I keep encountering an error. The error message I'm receiving is:
HTTP error occurred: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/order
{"code":700013,"msg":"Invalid content Type."}

Below is the script I am using to place the order:
import requests
import time
import hmac
import hashlib

# Your MEXC API key and secret
API_KEY = 'your_api_key'
API_SECRET = 'your_api_secret'

# Base URL for MEXC API
BASE_URL = 'https://api.mexc.com/api/v3'

# Function to create the signature for the request
def create_signature(query_string, secret):
    return hmac.new(secret.encode(), query_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Function to place a stop-limit order
def place_stop_limit_order():
    endpoint = '/order'
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
    
    # Parameters for the stop-limit order
    params = {
        'symbol': 'ETHUSDC',
        'side': 'BUY',
        'type': 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT',   # Order type
        'quantity': '0.01',         # Quantity to buy
        'price': '4000.01',          # Limit price
        'stopPrice': '4000',         # Stop price
        'timeInForce': 'GTC',        # Time in force
        'timestamp': timestamp
    }

    query_string = '&'.join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in sorted(params.items())])
    signature = create_signature(query_string, API_SECRET)
    
    headers = {
        'X-MEXC-APIKEY': API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  # Correct content type
    }

    # Adding signature to the query string
    query_string += f"&signature={signature}"

    # Make the request to place the order
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL + endpoint, headers=headers, data=query_string)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses (4xx and 5xx)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {err}")  # Print HTTP error
        print(response.text)  # Print the response content
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Other error occurred: {err}")  # Print other errors

    return response.json()

# Main function to place the stop-limit order
def main():
    result = place_stop_limit_order()
    print(f"Order placed: {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I have ensured that the Content-Type is set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as suggested in various documentation. Despite this, I still get the invalid content type error.
Could someone please help me identify what I might be doing wrong? Any suggestions or corrections would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

in question (not in comments) you could add link to documentation for this function in API

on page MEXC API I see link to python module mexc-api-sdk and maybe you should use it. OR you could check its source code to see how they send requests.post

maybe documentation for MEXC API has examples for command curl - so you could use pages like CurlConverter.com to convert it to Python. But sometimes it may create wrong code.

documentation for /api/v3/order? shows example POST /api/v3/order?symbol=MXUSDT&... and it means it doesn't send it as form but as query string (which needs params=' instead of data=

Documentation for /api/v3/order shows example
POST /api/v3/order?symbol=MXUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&quantity=50&price=0.1&timestamp={{timestamp}}&signature={{signature}}

and it means it doesn't send it as form but as query string
and this needs params= instead of data=
response = requests.post(..., params=query_string)


Example also doesn't care if parameters are in order so you may send dictionary without converting to string
response = requests.post(..., params=params)

